# How do I make the Java file chooser display in front of the NetBeans interface?

Tags: java, netbeans

This problem is due to the basic setup that I have, which is a simple yes/no verification before the program brings up a filechooser. How do I make the filechooser display in front of NetBeans? The program works, I just need the browse file window to appear up front.

```
package txtkeyverifier2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TxtKeyVerifier001 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Do you wish to continue yes/no: ");
    String answer = keyboard.nextLine();

    switch (answer) {
        case "yes":
        case "y": {

            ChooseFile fileChooser = new ChooseFile();
            File keyfile = fileChooser.getFile();

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(keyfile);
            String input = sc.nextLine();

            if (authenticate1(input)) {

                System.out.println("This program is working if this text is found within outputfile.txt.");

                File outputfile = new File("outputfile.txt");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
                System.setOut(ps);
                System.out.println("This program is working if this text is found within outputfile.txt.");

            } else if (authenticate2(input)) {

                System.out.println("It works.");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Wrong password.");
            }
        }
        break;
        case "no":
        case "n":

            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid entry");
            break;
    }
}

private static boolean authenticate1(String password1) {

    return ((password1.length() == 6)
            && (password1.matches("beep11"))
            && (password1.matches("beep11"))
            && (password1.matches("beep11")));
}

private static boolean authenticate2(String password2) {

    return ((password2.length() == 6)
            && (password2.matches("beep22"))
            && (password2.matches("beep22"))
            && (password2.matches("beep22")));
}
}

class ChooseFile {

private JFrame frame;

public ChooseFile() {

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.toFront();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public File getFile() {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    if (JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION == fc.showOpenDialog(null)) {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        return fc.getSelectedFile();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Next time select a file.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}

private void BringToFront() {
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `null` to `fc.showOpenDialog`, you should pass its parent, usually the `JFrame`'s content pane, returned by `frame.getContentPane()`

Comment: Works for eclipse anyway